# C# TCP: Receive data sent to TCPListener from TCPClient

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, client, listener

Yesterday I started a project where you can chat with people in a specific chat room in a C# Console Application. There is a TCPListener on the server-side that continuously listens for incoming connections and handles each incoming connection on a separate thread. On the client-side you can connect to this listener by entering an IP address and nickname and you are connected to the TCPListener.

I am able to send messages from **Client => Server** and the messages arrive at the server, but when multiple clients are connected the other clients won't see my message.

For instance, I have two clients connected to the listener: one with nickname 'user1' and one with nickname 'user2'. When user1 sends a message, the server receives it. When user2 sends a message, the server receives it too. But user1 does not see what user2 sent to the server and vice-versa.

**My question**

My question is:

> How can I make TCPClients connected to the TCPListener receive the messages from other TCPClients?

**Additional information**

I've added some comments to make it easy to understand the methods I used. The listener listens on port 8345.

**Client**

```
    public static void Connect(string serverIP, string nickname)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = null;
            MessageHelper helper = null;

            client.Connect(serverIP, PORT);
            stream = client.GetStream();
            helper = new MessageHelper(client, stream);
            helper.SendMessage($"!nickname={nickname}");

            Log("Connected!");

            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Get messages from other senders
                    helper.ReadMessage();
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }));

            receiveThread.Start();

            while (Util.IsClientConnected(client))
            {
                Console.Write(" > ");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        helper.SendMessage(message);
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        Log("The server closed unexpectedly.");
                    }
                }                        
            }

            Log("Disconnected.");
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Log("SocketException: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Server**

```
    public static bool IsListening;
    private const int PORT = 8345;

    public static void HandleClient(object _client)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)_client;
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        MessageHelper helper = null;
        var ipAddress = MessageHelper.GetIpInformation(client).IpAddress.ToString();
        stream = client.GetStream();
        helper = new MessageHelper(client, stream);

        // Initial read, assuming this will be a '!nickname' command it will set the nickname
        helper.ReadMessage();
        Log($"{helper.Nickname} ({ipAddress}) connected.");

        while (Util.IsClientConnected(client))
        {
            try
            {
                // Check every 300 ms for a new message and print it to the screen.
                helper.ReadMessage();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                Log($"{helper.Nickname} disconnected.");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }

    public static void StartListener()
    {
        TcpListener listener = null;
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;

        listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, PORT);
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            IsListening = true;
            Log($"Listener started at {ipAddress}:{PORT}.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        while (IsListening)
        {
            // Check if listener is handling a pending connection, if not, wait 250 ms.
            if (!listener.Pending())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                continue;
            }

            // Client connected, handle at a separate thread.
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }
```

**MessageHelper.cs**

```
public class MessageHelper
{
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public TcpClient Client { get; set; }
    public NetworkStream Stream { get; set; }

    public MessageHelper(TcpClient client, NetworkStream stream)
    {
        Client = client;
        Stream = stream;
    }

    public static IpInformation GetIpInformation(TcpClient client, bool isRemote = true)
    {
        string fullHostname;

        if (isRemote)
            fullHostname = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        else
            fullHostname = client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString();

        IpInformation info = new IpInformation()
        {
            IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(fullHostname.Split(':')[0]),
            Port = int.Parse(fullHostname.Split(':')[1])
        };

        return info;
    }

    public string GetMessageFormat(string message)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        return $" [{dateTime.ToShortTimeString()}] <{Nickname}>: {message}";
    }

    public void ReadMessage()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        int byteCount = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        string ipAddress = GetIpInformation(Client).IpAddress.ToString();
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, byteCount);

        // Check if message is a command
        if (message.StartsWith("!"))
        {
            try
            {
                // Command format is >> !command=value <<
                string[] commandSplit = message.TrimStart('!').Split('=');
                string command = commandSplit[0];
                string value = commandSplit[1];

                if (command == "nickname")
                {
                    Nickname = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log("This command is not found.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Regular message, print it to the console window.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine(GetMessageFormat(message));
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        if (!message.StartsWith("!"))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(GetMessageFormat(message));
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        else
        {
            // Issue the '!nickname' command
            if (message.StartsWith("!nickname"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Nickname = message.TrimStart('!').Split('=')[1];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    Log("Please enter an argument for this command.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest thing to do is receiving the message on the server and send it to all connected clients

Comment: @Kaj That sounds really promising! The only thing is that I don't have any idea how to achieve this because I am fairly new to programming with Sockets.

Comment: Socket programming needs a lot of understanding. But I'll give you the idea. Make a list of type TcpClient, then when a client connect, add it to the list. When the server receive the message, loop through the list and send the message to all clients in the list except the sender.

Comment: @Kaj I have been thinking about that in the first place. Thanks a lot though, I will try that again.

Comment: With TCP you can have only one sender and receiver on a connection.  So for everybody to get the messages the server has to send to all the clients every send/receive message for everybody to get all the traffic.  So the Server needs to have a List<Socket> so it can send messages to all clients.  To get the List<Socket> you need create your own Accept method that take every new connection and add to List<Socket> and when a disconnect occurs remove the Socket from the List.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MessageHelper.cs` class `ReadMessage` method you are not storing the messages or you are not broadcasting the messages to all the clients.

To broadcast

1. Create an Event in MessageHelper and raise the event at 
   `Console.WriteLine(GetMessageFormat(message));` .
2. Pass the message in
   EventHandler in the Event.
3. In Client.cs file, Handle the event to recieve all the messages

**Sample Code**

In `MessageHelper` Class declare event as

```
public event EventHandler ReadMessageEvent;
```

In `ReadMessage` Method at  `Console.WriteLine(GetMessageFormat(message));` replace with

```
if (ReadMessageEvent!= null)
        ReadMessageEvent.Invoke(GetMessageFormat(message), null);
```

In `Client` class try block add below code

```
helper.ReadMessageEvent += ReadMessageEvent_HandleEvent;

 private void ReadMessageEvent_HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string message = sender as string;
   Console.WriteLine(message);           
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will be finding out if this method works for me.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer since it's not a complete solution !

Comment: @Kaj Updaqted answer with sample code. I hope that should suffice to be an answer